# Flask Internal server error when rendering static files

Tags: flask

I am new to Flask and I am encountering a problem: when I return a message, such as:

app_setup.py

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return '''Hello World!'''
```

it works fine. However, when I try to render a static html file such as:

app_setup.py

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('static/index.html')
```

it gives me an Internal Server Error. How can i fix this?

N.B: I am running Flask with uWSGI and Nginx in Docker.

main.py

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

from .core import app_setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Only for debugging while developing
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates typically come out of a `templates/` subdirectory of the app, which is where `render_templates()` looks for them. (Things get slightly more complicated when you're using blueprints, but safe that thought, since you aren't.)

Create a `templates` directory, and move `index.html` there. Then

```
return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `render_templates()` go look for your static template file into the `/templates` subdirectory of your app. A good approach would be to create a templates directory, and move the static `index.html` there.

Although, if you do want to set a new directory to template static files, you could try the following when initializing the app:

```
import os
tmpl_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
# ...
app = Flask('myapp', template_folder=tmpl_dir)
```